# How to insert HTML in MySQL DB using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, html

How can we insert full HTML of a webpage into my table using Java?

Comment: HTML doesn't belong in a database.  You should rethink that design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do what follows:

Get your page's HTML somehow into a String variable:

```
String fullHtml = "";
```

Create a table with a text field

```
create table your_html_container (
     id int primary key autoincrement,
     content text not null
);
```

Insert html content using JDBC:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, user, password);
PreparedStatement pstmt = 
    conn.prepareStatement("insert into your_html_container (content) values (?)");
pstmt.setString(1, fullHtml); // this is your html string from step #1
pstmt.executeUpdate();
pstmt.close();
conn.close();
```

You are done.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `text` type in MySQL. Then use a simple `Statement` / `PreparedStatement` to insert the text.

What I'd suggest though is to have an html template outside the DB, and fill it with specific data obtained from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting full HTML pages in the DB, you may want to look into zipping the field. Should get pretty substantial space savings...